# MySQL и PDO не срабатывает

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Ниже пример кода:

```
$k = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO kategories SET user_id=$user_id, in_ex=?, name=?");
        $k->execute(array($_POST['in_ex'], $_POST['katName']));
```

Когда заменяю  ? на 'pyfxtybz' , то скрипт работает. Почему тогда со знаками вопросов не работает?
Ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, name=?' at
>   line 1' in C:\web\OpenServer\domains\test.loc\tools.php on line 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PDO::query() выполняет SQL запрос без подготовки и возвращает
>   результирующий набор (если есть) в виде объекта PDOStatement.

Вы пытаетесь через метод [query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php) использовать запрос для метода [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php).

Помимо этого у Вас неправильный `INSERT` запрос - смесь `INSERT` и `UPDATE`

Ваш код должен быть таким:

```
$k = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO kategories (user_id, in_ex, name) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$k->execute(array($user_id, $_POST['in_ex'], $_POST['katName']));
```

Comment: Точно, prepare нужно было использовать вместо query.

Comment: Спасибо помогли очень